# git cat-file using treeish notation

Tags: git

When using the command git cat-file as following:

```
git cat-file -p master^^{tree}
```

It works well and shows the content of the tree object, 2 commits in the past.

However, when using the same command, changing the ^^ for ~2, it shows the following error:

```
git cat-file -p master~2{tree}

fatal: Not a valid object name master~2{tree}
```

Is this syntax allowed? Otherwise, how could I retrieve the tree object 100 commits in the past?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first command is actually only going 1 commit into the past, not 2. The first caret is selecting the parent of `master`, but the second one is part of the `^{type}` syntax. To go to the parent's parent and convert to a tree, you need `master^^^{tree}`.

This also explains what's wrong with your second command: it needs to be `master~2^{tree}`.

Comment: Great! Yes, sorry, I mean 1 commit in the past. I tried with your suggestion and I works fine with master~2^{tree}. Thanks!